# Immutable Blob Storage - 10,000 container limit?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

It is my understanding that an Azure Storage account can have unlimited containers.

However, I would like to use the Azure Blob Storage - Immutable Storage Time Based Retention Policies as per:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage#time-based-retention-policies

On this page it specifies:

- For a storage account, the maximum number of containers with **locked** time-based immutable policies is 10,000.

Does this imply that for **unlocked** time-based immutable policies there is no limit though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question here too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/322524/immutable-blob-storage-10000-container-limit.html

> Yes, there is no limit on unlocked containers, at max you can lock 10,000 containers.
> Hope that clears this up. Let us know if you have further questions or issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no limit** to the number of blob containers.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry that my question was not clear. It was specifically about unlocked time-based immutable policies applied to containers and whether there was a limit on the number of containers that these policies can be applied to. Please see my own answer.